# I have a program running on the diagnostics of my iPhone called JS ON and I want to know what it's doing and how can I stop at

Tags: iphone

[image]
I have been getting hacked on my iPhone and I believe this program is doing something! I have did a factory reset many times. The program always returns??

Answer (score 1):

[JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) isn't the name of a program.

It's the name of a data format. It's the format you see there [with all the `{}`s and `:`s and things in `"`s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Example). That log file is just named "2017-02-18T01:22:39.json", with ".json" at the end, sort of like how names of HTML files might end with ".html", or names of JPEG image files might end with ".jpg". That ".json" is simply part of the file name, it's not the name of a program.

It's a pretty widely used format on computers and such, because it's easy for both humans *and* computers to write and read.

Nothing in your post identifies any programs or anything else. Whatever that log is you are looking at, it's in JSON format. That's all.

Since a huge number of things on your iPhone probably output JSON-formatted text, no amount of factory resets will stop it. "JSON" isn't a problem and factory resets would have no impact on that, just like there isn't a program named "JPEG" and a factory reset won't stop your camera from saving JPEG files.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Much appreciated. One more QA J.monkey.jar?? And j.son??   I looked these two up Wikipedia gave an answer of malware?? Any thoughts??

Comment: @Robbdemos I know what both of those are, and they are non-issues. And I just Googled for them to try to see what you are looking at and cannot find the "answer of malware" you speak of. My main thought is you should find a friend that understands a bit more about software to take a look for you. :) If you have any more issues please post them as new questions.

Comment: just as an aside JSON is a way of formatting data for JAVASCRIPT. A .JAR file is a JAVA  program (or part of a Java program). Tho they have similar names Java and Javascript bear no relation to each other